# exit status 255 : Crashed in liberty java web application in IBM Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I'm working on a web application using node.js and liberty java as a runtime in IBM Bluemix.

I'm using IBM devops service to edit my code.

After creating a default website, I wanted to change the layout of the webpage. So I added some new html files and css along with js in the webapp folder

[**Click here**:This is the image of project which has all the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFO51.png)

I'm facing [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g2g9.png) this problem while deploying and running my website in IBM bluemix....

Comment: No one on stack overflow is interested in this?
Dude im stuck here...!!

Comment: I suggest you to add more details about the crash... For example the applications logs through cf logs (appname) --recent

Comment: create a new app, and see if you face the same issue editing your code via devops

Comment: I added a couple more tags, so that more people will see it - bluemix is a big place and needs a little further qualification.

Comment: Thank you for helping me @ralphearle

Answer (score 0):

It would help to understand what you're trying to accomplish.  It appears that you're running a node.js app on the liberty runtime. I believe the node.js and liberty apps need to run on their own runtimes.